# Insert data to Azure Data Explorer through C#

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to ingest my application log data to Azure Data Explorer using Kusto.Data NuGet (C#). I am able to retrieve data using the below method but it's not working while retrieving data. Am I using the wrong pattern for insert query?

```
var kustoConnectionStringBuilder =
            new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(kustoUri, database)
            {
                FederatedSecurity = true,
                InitialCatalog = database,
                UserID = user,
                Password = password,
                Authority = tenantId
            };
            var client = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(kustoConnectionStringBuilder);
            string query = "ingest inline into table Device <| 1,DeviceId";
            client.ExecuteQuery(query);
```

**Error Message:** Syntax error: Query could not be parsed: A recognition error occurred. Can anyone please help me on this?
My Device table has two column for now: Id (int),Description (string)

Answer (score 1):

there are several issues with the code snippet you've published:

**a.** you're using an `ICslQueryProvider` instead of an `ICslAdminProvider`, and `ExecuteQuery()` instead of `ExecuteControlCommand()`. `.ingest` (or anything else that starts with a dot (`.`) is a control command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/#differentiating-control-commands-from-queries)

- examples can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-data
- and here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-samples-dotnet/tree/master/client

**b.** you're missing a dot (`.`) before `ingest` (should be `.ingest`).

**c.** you're using `direct ingestion` instead of `queued ingestion` (it's 'ok', as long as you understand this is for test purposes only). read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-ingestion/#ingestion-methods

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot! I am more clear on Kusto working model.